# How would I go about printing text from my android program?

Tags: android, printing

I would like to know how to print some text content from my android application to a physical printer. I post a similar question but the responses didn't seem to work for me. I would like to know some API's or any other alternatives that could sort my problem out. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First up, how would the Application interface with the printer?

Comment: should be through wifi friend

Comment: So the printer is a Network printer, correct? You'll be able to do this by first getting all the devices connected to the network, identify the printer, and then send a Network Printing message to that device.. http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/corp-net-guide/printserving-network.html

Comment: hmm ya correct. How do i do that in code friend. Any API's or coding documentations that could help.

Comment: I have no experience with this, Sorry. Check out different network printing protocols to see which are compatible with your printer. Some google searching should help.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have tried that worked out somewhat painlessly was to use Google's Cloud Print feature: http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/apps.html.

From their documentation towards the bottom of the above-referenced page is the following note about printing from your mobile device.  The trick is that your document is expected to be available from Gmail or from Google Docs.  If that is where you have your stuff, then this may be an option for you.

> If you access Gmail or Google Docs through your phone’s browser, you can print any email, document, spreadsheet, or other Docs file through Google Cloud Print. Using the new print2docs feature, you can also "print" any file you wish to your Docs account for safe keeping. Made by Google.  From your phone, go to http://m.google.com

Comment: hmm no friend, actually my solution requires printing dynamic variables. So storing on google docs is not an option. as far as i c it :(

Comment: To elaborate a little bit on my answer above: it looks like there are a number of Android Apps that can print documents from your device to Google Cloud Printer.  So in your case, if you can generate an intermediate document on your device (text file, PDF, etc.), then you might try looking at an app like: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dynamixsoftware.printershare

Comment: Alright, so check this out. My app is for printing receipts in say. So when a file is saved in the device every now and then its gonna be messy when the user switches to a third party app to print the document. Dont you think?

Comment: I agree with you that such a scenario would be messy for the user.  A little bit of searching around revealed the Google Cloud Print Android API: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android.  If you worked this into your app then printing should be quite hassle free.  I don't know of any other easy-to-use printing API systems for Android.